# Vite error during the deployment to heroku

Tags: typescript, vue.js, heroku, vite

My folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

My scripts:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "node main.mjs",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV='development' npx nodemon main.mjs",
    "build": "cd client && yarn build",
    "install-client": "cd client && yarn",
    "heroku-postbuild": "yarn install-client && yarn build"
  }
```

`client/package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.1",
    "typescript": "~4.6.3",
    "vite": "^2.9.1",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.33.9"
}
```

The error: `/bin/sh: 1: vue-tsc: not found`

My guess is that `devDependencies` on the client side aren't being fetched. But I did not set `NODE_ENV` to `production` so no idea why they aren't being fetched.

Is moving all the `devDependencies` to `dependencies` a good idea?

Comment: Why are you hosting it on Heroku initially? Do you need the Node.js paid part? Can't you bundle your app and host it for free on Netlify/Vercel?

Comment: And no, keep your `devDependencies` there, don't bring them into `dependencies`.

Comment: Also, since you do have a `client/package.json`, did you installed the packages in that directory?

Comment: @kissu I have an api server on the backend therefore I need to host it on heroku. It's basically a monorepo with both frontend and backend in it.
As for the client side packages, they are installed during build time. Take a look a the `heroku-postbuild`

Comment: [`devDependencies` should be installed](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1376), but it has a "smart" pruning feature, where it removes unused dependencies. Try disabling that with `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` (or replace NPM_CONFIG with YARN if that's what you're using)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely caused by one of two issues:

- Heroku is pruning devDependencies from production app
- Heroku was caching the node_modules from previous build

---

In order create a smaller slug size for apps, the Heroku's buildpack will prune out the devDependencies from the package.json at the end of the build, so that the slug will only include the dependencies that are listed at runtime.

You can disable this dependency pruning, by running:

```sh
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
```

Or, for Yarn

```sh
heroku config:set YARN_PRODUCTION=false
```

But if this is the case, and the missing dependency is also used at runtime, then it should be listed under `dependencies` rather than `devDependencies`.

---

Heroku, by default uses `npm ci` instead of `npm i`. So another option would be to switch this back, with:

```
heroku config:set USE_NPM_INSTALL=true
```

And to disable the cache:

```
heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
```

And worth also checking that you've specified the right NPM and Node version in your package.json (under `engines`). And that you've committed either a `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer! I ran `heroku config:set YARN_PRODUCTION=false` and it worked. I find it strange that `vue-tsc` is under `devDependencies` despite of following the Getting Started guide in the vite offical doc.

Answer (score 0):

With inspiration from @Lissy93's explanation, For those trying to deploy Vue 3 app with Vite to Heroku. Follow the instruction here https://www.codementor.io/@ravianand1988/easily-4-steps-to-continuous-delivery-auto-deploy-vue-js-app-on-heroku-xljk977pq (ignore the @vue/cli install and the vue-cli-service scripts) then set

```
NODE_ENV=development, 
NODE_MODULES_CACHE = false
```

in your heroku settings given that you're connecting your repo from github. Then have this in your scripts tag in package.json

```
...
"prestart": "npm run build",
"build": "npx vite build",
"start": "node server.js",
...
```

Then run your deployment again.